# Filter to only show data within the radius of a point using longitude and latitude in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, meteor

I am building an app where I am pulling live streaming data from Twitter. The bounding box property that is only supposed to show San Francisco but it is showing almost all of California. What can I use to filter out the data to only show the points that are inside of the radius of the longitude and latitude (under Red circle).

ca-tweet-locator.meteor.com

I am also open to finding out how to show data inside of a box.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question, not just a reference to your website.

Comment: I am looking for a formula to only pull information that pulls markers within the radius of a point using miles. I think it may be something similar to this but in javascript.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285686/i-want-to-only-show-markers-within-a-certain-radius-of-geolocation?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the distance between two LatLng points using a special formula.[1](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

For example:

```
function distance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2){
  var R = 6371; // km
  return Math.acos(Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) + 
                  Math.cos(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2) *
                  Math.cos(lon2-lon1)) * R;
}
```

So, using this , just test if the tweet is within the desired KM.

```
if (distance(circle.lat, circle.lon, tweet.lat, tweet.lon) <= desiredRadiusInKm){
  // include tweet
} else {
  // exclude tweet
}
```

EDIT:

Making it a little more obvious- you can filter your tweets by creating a filter:

```
function makeTweetFilter(circleCenterLatitude, circleCenterLongitude, circleRadiusInMi){
   var circleRadiusInKm = circleRadiusInMi * 1.6;
   return function tweetWithinCircle(tweet){
      return distance(circleCenterLatitude, circleCenterLongitude, tweet.lat, tweet.lon) <= circleRadiusInKm;
   }
}


var tweets = getSomeTweets();
var myFilter = makeTweetFilter(circle.lat, circle.lon, circle.radiusInMi);
var tweetsWithinCircle = _.filter(tweets, myFilter);
```

Comment: I am not looking for the distance between two points I am looking for a way to find the way to pull information from a radius around a point. Preferably using miles or kilometers.

Comment: You can tell if a point is within a circle by checking if the distance from the center of the circle to the point is less than the radius.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the best way is by checking one, and then the other.

Say my longitude is 81 meridians and latitude is 100 meridians.
My radius is 1 meridian.
If my chosen location's longitude is: greater than or equal to 81-radius(in this case 80) and less than or equal to 81+radius(in this case 82) then we can run the same checks in latitude...

```
myLong=81;
myLat=100;
otherLong=80;
otherLat=80;
radius=1;

if(otherLat>=myLat-radius&&otherLat<=myLat+radius){
   //Check For Longitude
   if(otherLong>=myLong-radius&&otherLong<=Mylong+radius){
      //Then There Is An Overlap/Collision
   }
}
```

Hope that is what you were asking...
You can put that inside a map of an array of tweets to iterate over every single one...
Also, It may be worth moving the inner if statement conditions up to be with the other if conditions (will be 4 conditions seperated by &&).

If you need more info, it may be worth googling for circle to point collision detection. 
http://jackdye.co.uk/collision-detection-2-point-circle/

Joe